# Is it possible to access a Windows MSSQL server from an instance of Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, command-line

I'm trying to assess the viability of using Linux within a very-much Windows environment for bash/scripting utilities to be performed. From the documentation I could find, ubuntu access is possible but it seems to be from where the SQL DB is installed in Linux, rather than in Windows. Are there any hoops to jump through to setup this access via Linux or Windows-Subsystem-Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking if you can connect to a SQL server (running on windows) from a Linux server, then yes you can...

SQL will respond to port 1433 (if you didn't change the default) and does not care the OS behind.

Same is true the other way around as well... if you run SSMS from windows and try to connect to a linux SQL Server, it will work too

Comment: There's also an open source [driver](https://www.freetds.org/) for tabular data stream, which works pretty well according to my experience.